# Detecting Navigation with Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I'm looking for a "best practice" (besides "don't do that") when using Puppeteer with a page that *may* (but not always) reload when a radio button is clicked, a select option is selected, etc.  The use case is I'm navigating an eCommerce page with options, and some of those options cause the page to reload, some of them don't.

I've tried hooking into the on("load") event to try and catch when this happens, and reset my page variable, but I can't get the "timing" correct, and still end up with execution context exceptions.  What I've resorted to is try/catching the execution context exceptions in a loop so I can retry.  Below is sort of what I'm talking about, and I'm in violent hatred of it (it's ugly, verbose, etc.):

```
    async evaluate(fn: EvaluateFn, ...args: any[]): Promise<any> {
        let result: ElementHandle | null = null;
        let page: Page | undefined = undefined;
        for(let attempt = 0; attempt < this.MAX_EXECUTION_RETRIES; attempt++) {
            try {
                if(page == undefined) {
                    // this.browser is an earlier instantiate instance of a Puppeteer Browser
                    const pages = await this.browser.pages();
                    page = pages[pages.length = 1];
                }
                result = await page.evaluate(fn, ...args);
                break;
            } catch(e) {
                if(attempt < this.MAX_EXECUTION_RETRIES - 1 && (e.message && e.message.indexOf("Execution context") != -1)) {
                    await sleep(this.EXECUTION_RETRY_DELAY);
                    page = undefined;
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Is there a better way to get notified or check if my page variable's execution context is no longer valid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer flow logic, check if navigation has occurred (vs wait for)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342023/puppeteer-flow-logic-check-if-navigation-has-occurred-vs-wait-for)

Comment: If I'm reading that thread correctly, it sounds like that thread is trying to find a reliable way to get when the page has changed when you are expecting it to change (the user hitting "try again").  My case is a little different, in that I just want to notified asynchronously if the page got changed, so that I don't use a page context that is borked.

Comment: It seems that's pretty much what `page.on("load" ... )` already offers, which isn't going to be easy to sync with the main line promise chain as you discovered. Is a test like `await el.click() ; if (await didReload()) { /* try again or do whatever */ } else { /* do something else */ }` fit your needs, assuming we can write a `didReload`? If so, I do think it's similar to the other question, although the solutions proposed there seem generally unsatisfying at the time of writing.

Comment: I like the idea of a "didReload" type of check, which seems cleaner than implementing with an exception handler.  Would you see this as being a property/method of a Page object?

Comment: `page` is from the library, so I wouldn't want to touch it. The function I'm proposing is just a concept to show how it'd work in the control flow. I'm not 100% sure how to implement it but I have a few ideas that hopefully aren't too hacky and avoid polling or race conditions. I'm mostly curious myself.

Comment: Still no answer to this pretty common scenario ? I can’t use waitForNavigation since in case of no network call it will end up with a dead lock or at least a timeout. And with timeout il not able to determine if it’s because page was to slow to load or because there was no network call…